# PHP pointing back to document root

Tags: php, document-root

Not sure if I'm using this the right way...

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/overall/header.php"
```

My page is in a subdirectory, and I want to include elements from other directories with a path based on the root.

Answer (score 2):

The $_SERVER variables are global in php runtime, not safe to used.

the code 
`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = 'A_BAD_PATH';`
 takes effect. The code after this can't get the right variable.

You should use __FILE__, a constant point the current file's path, and define a constant point to the root directory.

code sample:

```
define('CURRENT_DIR', dirname(\__FILE__));
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(CURRENT_DIR + '/..');
require(ROOT_DIR + '/some/path/to/init.php');
```

see more about __FILE__ and other magic constants http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php